# How do I use regex to return text following specific prefixes?

Tags: regex

I'm using an application called Firemon which uses regex to pull text out of various fields. I'm unsure what specific version of regex it uses, I can't find a reference to this in the documentation.

My raw text will always be in the following format:

```
CM: 12345 
APP: App Name 
BZU: Dept Name 
REQ: First Last 
JST: Text text text text.
```

CM will always be an integer, JST will be sentence that may span multiple lines, and the other fields will be strings that consist of 1-2 words - and there's always a return after each section.

The application, Firemon, has me create a regex entry for each field. Something simple that looks for each prefix and then a return should work, because I return after each value. I've tried several variations, such as "BZU:\s*(.*)", but can't seem to find something that works.

EDIT: To be clear I'm trying to get the value after each prefix. Firemon has a section for each field. "APP" for example is a field. I need a regex example to find "APP:" and return the text after it. So something as simple as regex that identifies "APP:", and grabs everything after the : and before the return would probably work.

Comment: If it's perl compatible, you should use `[\s]*` instead of `\s*`. `\s` references a character class, thus it must be used within anhular brackets => `BZU:[\s]*(.*)`

Comment: I didn't understand clearly but if you want to match what is after sentence you can use `(?=\w+ )(.*)`

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. In the example text above I'm wanting the values after each prefix, such as "App Name" and "First Last".

Comment: Cant believe no answer yet, good question

Comment: Then i think my answer is correct with `(?=\w+ )(.*)` in each match you will catch text after prefix and space. If is incorrect write here to rewrite and give me text where this regexp is incorrect.

Comment: you should try it and post it as an answer then

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?=\w+ )(.*)`

Positive lookahead will remove prefix and space character from match groups and you will in each match  get text after space.

Comment: Reason I asked is because if you did then you should post your proof, which you have in your comment. I would edit the answer and throw that link in there for proof. I'll also upvote you since you (what seems to be) have the correct answer xD.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late to the game, but maybe this is still an issue.
In the more recent versions of FireMon, sample regexes are provided. For instance:

> jst:\s*([^;]*?)\s*;

will match on:

> jst:anything in here;

and result in

> anything in here